# Javascript set then display a cookie value

Tags: javascript, cookies

My problem seems to be easy but I can't make it work; I want to set a cookie variable called "splash" then display it (later I want use in IF clause)
Here is my code :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
document.cookie =  "splash=" + encodeURIComponent("blue theme")
   var re = new RegExp(splash + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    alert(value);
   </script>
   </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `splash` defined?

Comment: this is a variable that I will set directly in cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following function to set and get Cookie

```
function createCookie(name, value, days)
{
    if(days)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else
    {
        var expires = "";
    }
    var fixedName = '';
    name = fixedName + name;
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) 
{
   var value = "; " + document.cookie;
   var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
   if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
function eraseCookie(name) 
{
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Comment: I used your code :    <body onload="createCookie('splash','true','1')">
<button onclick="alert(getCookie('splash'))">Click me</button> But I get Undefined

Comment: After page load please check in console cookie with splash is created or not.

Comment: Where have you written these functions?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your regex to include splash as part of the quoted string.  Even though spash is the variable you're using in the cookie, it does not automatically become a javascript variable.

```
document.cookie = "splash=" + encodeURIComponent("blue theme")
var re = new RegExp("splash=([^;]+)");
var theme = re.exec(document.cookie)[1];
```

`re.exec` returns an array.  the first element is the entire matched string (including `splash=`).  The second is your capture group (`blue%20theme`).